# Is it possible to update one defined router parameter?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

The standard way to navigate to a route is

```
this.router.navigate(["/details", "30"]
```

with the following route configuration:

```
{ path: "details/:id", component: TestRouteComponent }
```

The constructor of my class would be

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

---

What I want to do is to just update the `id` of the *current* route.

Something like

```
this.route.params.id = 10;
```

and then navigate to that route

```
this.router.navigate(this.route);
```

Is that possible with angular routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manipulate `params` since this is an `Observable`.
You can do something like this:

```
router.navigate(['..', 2], { relativeTo: route });
```

The two dots are indicating that you move one level up.

```
from `welcome/1` to `welcome`
```

After that your param is appended to the route.

But I wonder if there is a nicer way to do a simple change of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right, that you want to react on changes inside a component when the params of its route has changed?

When yes, you do not want to trigger a new navigation.
You simply subscribe to changes of `params`.

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      /* access updated params and trigger further actions */
  }
}
```

Now if you have multiple links (e.g. routerLink) pointing to your component having just different parameters the router will detect that no new route has to be activated.
Therefore you cann subscribe to `params` or `paramMap`.

[paramMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap) gives you more control accessing certain parameters of the route.